How To Introspect a Retrieved CRD To Set Up A new_class and kr8s.get
I'm trying to do a kr8s get on a CRD I installed in a cluster.  I'm not very familiar with API calls and have had a tough time figuring out how to get everything configured.  I can use get_crd to retrieve the CRD but my get is still not working.  It looks something like this:
mycrd = get_crd('mycrdnames')

MyClass = new_class(
        kind="mycrdname", 
        version="example.com",        
        namespaced=False,
        asyncio=True,
    )

myclass = MyClass({})

kc.get("mycrdnames/example.com", namespace="mynamespace", api=mycrd.api)

ValueError: Unknown API version, base must be specified.

I'm wondering:

Is the information I need to properly configure the new_class and the get invocation already available in the retrieved CRD?  If so, how do I extract it?

If not, where can I find the required info (e.g. what base should be)?



This wasn't altogether clear to me either, but I think you might want something like:
kc.get("mycrdnames", "example.com/v1alpha1", namespace="mynamespace")
Which should give you a list of matching resources in your 'mynamespace'. I added a version here as you should also be defining a version field in your CRD.  Registering the new class with new_class will only be required if you want to create instances of that CR kind, but that syntax would be something like:
import kr8s
from kr8s.objects import new_class

MyClass = new_class(
        kind="mycrdname", 
        version="example.com/v1alpha1",        
        namespaced=True,
        asyncio=False )

